# Changes made to mesh does not appear in final render but appers in viewport render

Tags: rendering, mesh, knife-tool

I did some detailing on a mesh with the knife tool, the details appear in the rendered viewport but when I render it out, either in cycles or eevee the details dont show, it renders the mesh how it was before I did the detailing, i tried applying the scale, unwraping it but nothing works can you help me?
[image: This is the render in the viewport]

[image: And this the final render]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe you created a backup copy of the object, hid it from the viewport, then did your editing. Hiding it from the viewport does not prevent it from being rendered however.

If you click the little *Filter Dropdown* above the scene collection hierarchy in the *Outliner*, you can enable the *Disable in Render* restriction toggle, which allows you to also prevent objects from being rendered by clicking that icon in the hierarchy.